# How do I find out which RPM was used to install PHP?

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm

I have PHP installed on a server and I'd like to know which RPM it was build off of (`webtatic` or `remi`). How do I find this out.

Also, how would I find out if and when that changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rpm` command to find out information about a particular package:

```
$ rpm -qi php
Name        : php                          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.3.8                             Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 3.fc14                        Build Date: Wed 28 Sep 2011 01:40:37 PM EDT
Install Date: Wed 04 Jul 2012 12:42:03 PM EDT      Build Host: x86-12.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: php-5.3.8-3.fc14.src.rpm
Size        : 3773261                          License: PHP
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Wed 28 Sep 2011 10:20:06 AM EDT, Key ID 421caddb97a1071f
Packager    : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Summary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
Description :
PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages. PHP also
offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.

The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

The line you're interested in is Source RPM. The build date is also in this information.

#### Alternative executable

If you happen not to know the name of the package that a given executable is provided by, you can back into this information too:

```
$ type -a php
php is /usr/bin/php

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/php
php-cli-5.3.8-3.fc14.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
[root@jimmy ~]# which php
/usr/bin/php
[root@jimmy ~]# rpm -qf /usr/bin/php
php-cli-5.3.1-1.el5.remi
[root@jimmy ~]#
```

Then if you want to know more about the package, use "rpm -qi php" like slm said.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check `rpm` installation history with timestamp:

```
#rpm -qa --last
```